# How do I update the value of a javascript variable inside an async function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm using `AWS` to upload files to an `S3` bucket. In the below code snippet, I'd like to update the value of `uploadId` but the the value returns `undefined`. I know its because the last line completes before the `s3...` block.
How do I kind of wait for the s3 block to complete before returning the updated value of `uploadId`?

```
let uploadId
let params = { Bucket: s3_bucket, Key: filename, ContentType: filetype }
s3.createMultipartUpload(params, (err, data) => {
    uploadId = data.uploadId
    console.log(uploadId)
    console.log("uploadId err: ", err)
})
return uploadId
```

Comment: Return a promise intead. [Here](https://medium.com/@samthor/js-callbacks-to-promises-541adc46c07c) is an example.

Comment: Are you sure your S3 settings are correct ? I'm not sure the problem is about async. Could you print the `err` variable ?

Comment: There's no error. When I log the uploadId I get the correct string. But that return statement is reached before s3 has had time to finish its operation. I'm trying to make it into a promise but so far the syntax still confuses me. I see `setTimeOut` in a lot of examples and I'm not sure what its role is.

Comment: `await s3.createMultipartUpload(params)` also throws an error `await is a reserved word`.